# How to use FormComponentPanel for FileUpload Field in Apache wicket 9.x?

Tags: file-upload, wicket

I am trying to create FileUploadPanel that can be used in the form.
But however at runtime I facing some conversion error, I did debug the code it is going to the ConverterLocater.class in the wicket-core jar there it fails on the typecasting.

So when I debug I found filename is passed a in the  below method `public C convertToObject(String value, Locale locale)`  and in the conversion it fails because the value is string and it trying to caste to fileUpload.class.

Error:

```
throw (new ConversionException("Could not convert value: " + value + " to type: " + theType.getName() + ". Could not find compatible converter.")).setSourceValue(value);
```

Here value is passed as file name and theType is FileUpload.

I referred some examples, there setType is mandatory so I tried to set with String.class
but again next time fileUpload class was failing.

```
 Could not convert value: test.pdf to type: org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.upload.FileUpload. Could not find compatible converter.
```

Comment: Show us your code please

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

1. Model name parameter  was the issue, after changing this to List it got fixed.

> ```
> private List<FileUpload> fileUploads = new ArrayList<FileUpload>();
>
>  new MultiFileUploadField("fileField",new PropertyModel(this,"fileUploads"),maxFiles)
> ```